# Unable to produce symbol \{ using the STIX package

Tags: fonts, packages, math-fonts

Recently I became aware of the `STIX` package, and I tried to give a shot by replacing the `helvet` package.

The problem is that I am unable to produce the `{` symbol. If I understood correctly, I can produce the above symbol by using the `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` commands, respectively, into math-mode. However, this procedure doesn't work.

Here is an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bbm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\Omega=\lbrace O:l_o=1,C:l_o=0,B:0<l_o<1 \rbrace
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIX}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\Omega=\lbrace O:l_o=1,C:l_o=0,B:0<l_o<1 \rbrace
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so `amsfonts` and `amssymb` packages are unnecessary?

Comment: @Yorgos Yes, `stix` already provides substitutes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest the XITS font by Khaled Hosny instead of STIX.  As one might guess from the name, XITS is an hommage to STIX, but with refined shapes and a much wider range of glyphs and distributed as a Unicode math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}% loads fontspec
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\Omega=\lbrace O:l_o=1,C:l_o=0,B:0<l_o<1 \rbrace
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Is the documentation the same between `stix` and `xits` package? I mean, that the commands apply to the former package apply also to the latter package?